Проблема со скачиванием пакетов для проекта unity через диспетчер NuGet
Скачал пакет для использования в unity-проекте через диспетчер пакетов NuGet. Пакет появился, но я всё-равно получаю ошибку, говорящую о том, что мой именное пространство не найдено. А спустя некоторое время пакет и вовсе пропадает из вкладки "Ссылки" обозревателя проектов в VS code. Объясните пожалуйста, как установить пакет для Unity так, чтобы он работал и не пропадал.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать отдельными вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Проблема решена. Для того, чтобы успешно установить тот или иной пакет для Unity-проекта, и использовать его в нём, скорей всего, понадобится специальный Unity-пакет NuGet for Unity.
После его установки все пакеты прекрасно работают.
